# error on if condition java

Tags: java

```
public class SomeClass{

    public static void main (String[] args){
        if(true) int a = 0;// this is being considered as an error 
        if(true){
            int b =0;
        }//this works pretty fine
    }
}//end class
```

In the above class first if statement is showing an compilation error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on token "int", delete this token
    a cannot be resolved to a variable
```

However second if statement works fine. I just cannot figure it out myself. I know it is of no use declaring a variable in a single statement `if`. How those two statements are different can some one please explain me. Excuse me if the question is really simple.

Comment: In the second example, you could add code to use `b`, whereas it is very hard to contrive an example where you could use `a`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do declarations following conditions of control structures need to be in a block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647323/why-do-declarations-following-conditions-of-control-structures-need-to-be-in-a-b)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is specified in the java language specification. The `IfThenStatement` is specified as

> `if ( Expression ) Statement`

`int a = 0;` is not a statement, but a `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement` (which is *not* a subtype of `Statement`). But a `Block` is a `Statement` and a `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement` is legal content of a block.

```
 if (true) int a = 0;
           ^--------^    LocalVariableDeclarationStatement, not allowed here!

 if (true) {int a = 0;}
           ^----------^  Statement (Block), allowed.
```

**Reference**

- [Local Variable Declaration Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4)
- [Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5)
- [The If Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9)

Answer (score 13):

To define the scope of `int a` you need curly braces. That's why you get compiler error for

```
if(true) int a = 0;
```

while this works :

```
if(true){
    int b =0;
}
```

See [JLS §14.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) for if statements,

```
IfThenStatement:
    if ( Expression ) Statement
```

While in `if(true) int a = 0;`, `int a = 0` is `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement`

Answer (score 5):

From the java language specification, §14.2, you can see that a *LocalVariableDeclaration* is not a *Statement*, and thus can only occur in a *BlockStatement*:

```
BlockStatement:
    LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
    ClassDeclaration
    Statement
```

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf

Answer (score 0):

define a variable separately. And assign the value you want inside If. If you do it this way it will only be a variable inside the if block. But since you have one line if block its really not meaningful.

Comment: i have tried that it works fine. I wanted to know why my above code was not working.